How to compare and output the similarities between two files in powershell?
I need to compare two files in powershell to find the similarities between both and output it.
For example
a.txt:
words are easy to understand

buses drive very fast

john had to go and work hard

b.txt:
buses drive very slow

words are not always easy to understand

stack overflow is great

I worked hard yesterday.


So the output it should give me is:
words

understand

buses

john

hard

etc.

It shouldn't be comparing lines but instead comparing the entirety of the text for common words/strings.
Thanks,
I tried using the compare-Object but I might be using it in a way where its comparing the txt files line by line in which I would like it to read the whole doc on both files and print the words or strings that are found on both.

you need to use -split after reading the content but this may still produce unexpected result, i.e.: you have yesterday. on one side and in the other side you may have just yesterday without the dot then that one wouldn't be matched

@Martheen Sorry I was just writing up something quick but John shouldn't be there. I wrote etc. as a catch all for the same words.

So you're looking for individual words that occur in both files?

@MathiasR.Jessen Yes

@SantiagoSquarzon Split after reading the content?

Are these just words, only letters a to z or the words can have symbols / digits ?

they can have symbols. Now that I think about it, this may be more complicated than I thought because in one txt the words have " " marks around each word and in the other text they do not. :/

indeed, it is not easy. Compare-Object (-split (Get-Content .\a.txt -Raw)) (-split (Get-Content .\b.txt -Raw)) -IncludeEqual | ? SideIndicator -eq '==' can give you a place where to start but you will be losing words for sure

@SantiagoSquarzon Thanks! I think I have an idea to take a different approach to this.

you can use git file hash :
$file1Hash = Get-FileHash -Path $file1Path
$file2Hash = Get-FileHash -Path $file2Path
if ($file1Hash.Hash -eq $file2Hash.Hash) {
Write-Output "Files are identical"
} else {
Write-Output "Files are different"
}

It needs to output the individual words or strings found, not just say whether or not the files are exactly the same or not.

This might be a pretty bad solution but it will do the job for the example you provided.
As Santiago pointed out above you might still miss words that end in anything but a dot if you dont make sure to replace those characters.
Script

$a = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]  
$b = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]

(get-content .\a.txt).replace(".",'').Trim().Split('') | Select-String -Pattern "\w" | ForEach-Object {$a.Add($_)}
(get-content .\b.txt).replace(".",'').Trim().Split('') | Select-String -Pattern "\w" | ForEach-Object {$b.Add($_)}

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject


Output

words
are
drive
very
easy
to
understand
hard


If you specifically only needs to find the words common to both files:
$FirstWordList = Get-Content $FirstFilePath | ForEach-Object { $_ -isplit '[^\w]' } | Where-Object { $_ } | Sort-Object 
$SecondWordList = Get-Content $SecondFilePath | ForEach-Object { $_ -isplit '[^\w]' } | Where-Object { $_ } | Sort-Object -Unique


$CommonWords = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FirstWordList -DifferenceObject $SecondWordList -IncludeEqual | 
    Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -EQ '==' | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

$CommonWords here is a regular string array
otherwise, if you need\want\ to get the various differences:
$FirstWordList = Get-Content $FirstFilePath | ForEach-Object { $_ -isplit '[^\w]' } | Where-Object { $_ } | Sort-Object 
$SecondWordList = Get-Content $SecondFilePath | ForEach-Object { $_ -isplit '[^\w]' } | Where-Object { $_ } | Sort-Object -Unique

$CommonWords = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$FirstOnlyWords = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$SecondOnlyWords = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FirstWordList -DifferenceObject $SecondWordList -IncludeEqual |
    ForEach-Object {
        switch ($_) {
            { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' } { $CommonWords.Add($_.InputObject) ; break }
            { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } { $FirstOnlyWords.Add($_.InputObject); break }
            { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } { $SecondOnlyWords.Add($_.InputObject); break }
            default { <# do nothing #> }
        }
    }

